# NTP timestamp to UTC; 32 bit unsigned seconds + 32 bit fraction field

Tags: java, utc, ntp

T1 = C50204ECEC42EE92

T2 = C50204EBD3E8DDA4

The timestamp format includes the first 32-bit unsigned seconds as a field spanning 136 years and the 32-bit fraction field resolving 232 picoseconds.

T1 can be resolved as Sep 27, 2004 03:18:04.922896299 UTC. How can I write a program to convert T2 or similar into UTC time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: 0.922896299 = 0xEC42EE92 / 0x100000000

Comment: I tried to use the built in java DateTime method as is recommended in other questions. In this context I could not get that to solve my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make people do your work for you, rather than encountering puzzling, technical difficulties. What did you do, with these things you tried, that didn't give out results you expected?

Comment: I call this a duplicate. It’s even the same example value, C50204ECEC42EE92.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static ZonedDateTime parseNtp(String ts) {
    long seconds = Long.parseLong(ts.substring(0, 8), 16);
    long fraction = Long.parseLong(ts.substring(8), 16);
    return LocalDateTime.parse("1900-01-01T00:00:00").atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
            .plusSeconds(seconds)
            .plusNanos((long)(1000000000.0 / (1L << 32) * fraction));
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/NIGDvT)